Calculate the number of quarters two dates span across
I'm trying to come up with a formula to calculate the number of calendar quarters two dates will span across.
For example, if StartDate is 17 JUL 2023 and EndDate 9 JUL 2024, the formula should return 5:
From 17/07/2023 to 30/09/2023 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/10/2023 to 31/12/2023 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/01/2024 to 31/03/2024 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/04/2024 to 30/06/2024 - 1 calendar quarter
From 01/07/2024 to 09/07/2024 - 1 calendar quarter

In Excel, I managed to get it with =1+ROUNDUP(12*YEARFRAC(StartDate,EndDate,1)/3,0) or =LET(dts,SEQUENCE(DATE(EndDate)-DATE(StartDate),1,DATE(StartDate)),ROWS(UNIQUE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(dts)/3,0)&YEAR(dts)))) but I can't find the YEARFRAC equivalent in SF, or maybe I'm stuck on the wrong approach?

Are you looking for literally the number of quarters that the dates are in, or at the number of quarters between the dates? Because your first formula seems to be calculating the latter. Use e.g. 17/7/2023 and 18/07/2024 and it will give you 6 quarters, while in your example it's still counted as 5 quarters.

From the excel docs:

YEARFRAC will return the number of days between two dates as a year
fraction, in decimal form

If you substract 2 dates in Salesforce formulas, it will give you the number of days between them. Divide that by the number of days in the year and you will get a year fraction.
So you could represent your formula 1 by:
1 + MCEILING( 12 * ( (EndDate - StartDate) / 365) / 3)

NOTE: this is not taking into account leap year. In principle, you should correct for leap years as well.
However, as pointed out in my note, this is not a correct way of calculating it as you are dependent on which day of the month the startdate and enddate are in, while you actually don't care about that. Use e.g. 17/7/2023 and 18/07/2024 and it will give you 6 quarters, while in your example it's still counted as 5 quarters.
But you actually only care about the quarter they're in. So if you could determine the quarter of both dates and subtract those from each other, you'd get the right quarter-counter.
Let's approach it like this:

a difference in years counts as 4 quarters.
the quarter of a certain month can be found by applying the modulo 4. Do this for both months and subtract them from each other to find the month-based difference in quarters (on top of the yearly difference)
add 1 quarter because you want to count both the start and the end quarter


    4 * (YEAR(EndDate) - YEAR(StartDate))
    +(MOD(MONTH(EndDate),4) - MOD(MONTH(StartDate),4))
    +1


It is the perfect answer and you taught me how to approach it, thank you so much!
